# django-allauth ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER=None does not work

Tags: django, django-allauth

I know `django-allauth` setting [`ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEBER`](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) should work as follows:

```
None:  optionally remember, depending on user input
True:  always remember
False: never remember
```

But in my case, when `ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER` with `None`, then no matter whether the user chooses to check `remember me` or not, it does not work.

When using `ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER` with `True` or `False`, then it works as documented.

Answer (score 0):

With django-allauth==0.51.0, I see the `ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER = None` works as expected.

Here is what I did:

1. I log in with "remember me" checked.
2. I quit Chrome browser.
3. I reopen Chrome browser, and I am in log in page.
4. I log out and log back in with "remember me" unchecked.
5. I quit Chrome browser again.
6. I reopen Chrome browser, and I have been logged out.

I guess close browser is necessary to force log out. In `allauth`, it sets `set_expiry(0)` when `remember == None`.

```py
        if remember:
            request.session.set_expiry(app_settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE)
        else:
            request.session.set_expiry(0)
```

According to Django official document for `set_expiry` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry):

- If `value` is 0, the user’s session cookie will expire when the user’s web browser is closed.